# MapServer on Windows Server 2019 from MS4W

Tags: mapserver, ms4w

I have installed MapServer from MS4W on a Windows Server 2019 machine on port 8081 but it won't find the home page http://127.0.0.1:8081/ for some reason.  8081 is not in conflict and has been opened both directions in the firewall too.  Please help.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the developer (and the company, GatewayGeo) behind the product that you're using, MS4W.

Some steps for you to tackle:

- open in a text editor (Notepad++) the Apache error log: /ms4w/Apache/logs/error_log.txt
- take a look at the contents and see if it lists any errors (you could paste it here to get more feedback)
- now open a command prompt (run as Administrator) and execute:

  ```
    cd ms4w
    setenv.bat
    apache-restart.bat
  ```
- take a look at the response from that install command, does it give any error? (you could paste it here to get more feedback)
- recheck the error_log.txt file for any additional errors (you could paste it here to get more feedback)
- if you receive an error that the Apache MS4W Web Service service is not installed, in that same command prompt window (run as Administrator) :

  ```
    cd ms4w
    setenv.bat
    apache-install.bat
  ```

  and re-check the error_log.txt file for any additional errors (you could paste it here to get more feedback)
- also when you ran the installer, be sure that you followed its instructions to install at the root of a drive (eg. C:/), so after the installation you have a new path of C:/ms4w (and C:/ms4w/apps/  etc.)

---

The issue was on my side, as some recent MS4W installer changes were affecting just WinServer 2019 installs.  Fixed on 2021-03-27 and the new setup.exe installer is ready at [https:/ms4w.com](https://ms4w.com).